# Want to print a table dynamically php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called *appointment* and the fields are doctor, date, time, appuser(i.e patients). I want to print the first table which is shown in the link. I have displayed the second one but now I want to change it to the first one.

[image: I want to display first one, see Image]

This is my current code for the second table:

```
<div id="grid"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Time</li>
        <li>Doctor Name</li>            
        <li>Patient Name</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php   

    if($_POST['submit'] == "Search")
    {
        $select= $_POST['datesel'];
        $s = mysql_query("select * from appntt where date = '".$select."'");
    }
    else
    {
        $d= date("j/n/Y");
        $s=mysql_query("select * from appointment where date = '".$d."' ORDER BY time ASC");
    }
    $a=1;

    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
        if($fetch['time'] > '12:00')
        {
            $y = $fetch['time'].' PM';
        }
        else
        {
            $y= $fetch['time'].' AM';
        }

?>          
<div id="grid1">
    <ul>             
        <li><?php echo $y; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $fetch['doctor']; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $fetch['appuser']; ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php $a++; } ?>
```

Comment: time should vary from 08:00 to 18:00

Comment: What are you currently doing? What have you tried to display the first table? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried, but didn't found any way or logic to print this

Comment: Then at least show us how you are creating the second table

Comment: this is about second table: http://pastebin.com/wN9v0fBz

Comment: Please, avoid at all means giving links to your work. You should provide it all within your original post.

Comment: BTW below your question is a link named "edit", where you can modify the original question.

Comment: I guess you need to order the results in an array first and create the table based on the array, when you processed all results.

Comment: Downvoted, for asking for special attention over other questions, and for not responding to the helpful answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first order the results in an array in php and then print the table based upon this array.

First we need an array to sort the query results. This array will be two-dimensional in the end. We also need to remember all doctors, because it would be more work to extract them from the sorted appointments:

```
$table = []; //The array for the sorted appointments
$doctors = []; //The array for the doctors
```

Then we need to process the query results and sort them into the array:

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
    // The keys of the first dimension will be the appointment time 
    // and the key of the second dimension will be the doctor
    // So we can access a specific appointment by $table[time][doctor]
    $table[$fetch['time']][$fetch['doctor'] = $fetch['appuser'];

    //save the doctors name
    $doctors[] = $fetch['doctor'];
}
array_unique($doctors); // delete duplicate values, so that we have just
                        // the names of all the doctors
```

Now we need to print the table:

```
> <table> 
    <tr>
        <td> TIME </td> <? 
        foreach($doctors as $doctor){
            > <td> <? echo $doctor > </td> <? //print the header
        }
    > </tr> <?
// Depending on the result of your query, 
// you might need to order the array first or the times will be mixed up.
foreach($array as $time=>$appointments){ //loop over all the times. 
    > <tr> 
        <td> <? echo $time; > </td> <? //first column: print appointment time
        foreach($doctors as $doctor){
            > <td> <?
                if($appointments[$doctor] != null){
                    echo $appointments[$doctor]; //other columns: print patient name
                }
                // if there is no appointment, you might need to add a 
                // non-breakable-space to the cell
            > </td> <?
        }
    > </tr> <?
}
> </table>
```

This will hopefully do the trick. I can't guarantee that it works like this out of the box, because I can't test it, but I think you can get the idea.

On a side note: **never** plug values from the user directly into database-queries! This makes you vulnerable to SQL-injection.